# HtmlUnitDriver writes logs in my personal Log4J files

Tags: java, log4j, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I wrote crawlers for 3 different sites and run the crawlers in 3 threads. For each crawler I use single logger. 
My 'log4j.properties' file looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, ZDNET, CNET, GOOGLEPLAY

log4j.appender.ZDNET=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ZDNET.File=logs/zdnet.log
log4j.appender.ZDNET.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.ZDNET.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.ZDNET.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ZDNET.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n

log4j.appender.CNET=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CNET.File=logs/cnet.log
log4j.appender.CNET.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.CNET.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.CNET.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CNET.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n

log4j.appender.GOOGLEPLAY=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.GOOGLEPLAY.File=logs/googlePlay.log
log4j.appender.GOOGLEPLAY.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.GOOGLEPLAY.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.GOOGLEPLAY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.GOOGLEPLAY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n

log4j.category.zdNetLogger=DEBUG, ZDNET
log4j.additivity.zdNetLogger=false

log4j.category.cNetLogger=DEBUG, CNET
log4j.additivity.cNetLogger=false

log4j.category.googlePlayLogger=DEBUG, GOOGLEPLAY
log4j.additivity.googlePlayLogger=false
```

In java, i use the following code for writing my logs

```
final Logger APK_LOG = Logger.getLogger("googlePlayLogger");
final Logger C_NET_LOG = Logger.getLogger("cNetLogger");
final Logger ZD_NET_LOG = Logger.getLogger("zdNetLogger");
....
ZD_NET_LOG.info("1");
C_NET_LOG.info("2");
APK_LOG.info("3");
```

Everything worked fine, until I began to use Selenium + HtmlUnit + HtmlUnitDriver. 
After that, when i run my program, 3 log files (zdnet.log, cnet.log, googlePlay.log) filled by logs from HtmlUnitDriver.
Log info from my files (zdnet.log, cnet.log, googlePlay.log) after that:

```
2015-06-16 02:47:08 DEBUG - Get page for window named '', using WebRequest[<url="about:blank", GET, EncodingType[name=application/x-www-form-urlencoded], [], {Accept=image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, */*, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate}, null>]
2015-06-16 02:47:08 DEBUG - setEnclosedPage: HtmlPage(about:blank)@945834833
2015-06-16 02:47:08 DEBUG - destroyChildren
2015-06-16 02:47:08 DEBUG - Encoding found in HTTP headers: 'UTF-8'.
2015-06-16 02:47:08 DEBUG - Mapping java.lang.Object to HTMLCollection
2015-06-16 02:47:08 DEBUG - Mapping com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSpan to HTMLSpanElement
```

Any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because both [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/) and [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sf.net) uses log4j to also write their logs.

Your `rootLogger` defines `trace` level, so it writes everything.

Please add the below to allow only `error` level messages for HttpClient and HtmlUnit.

```
log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=error
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=error
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But it's not good for me. Because in first 10 seconds i got ~100 lines with 'error' logs (but all works fine).
    `log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=OFF`
    `log4j.logger.org.apache.http=OFF`
solved my problem.